# How to set dash or dotted line in a colour looped gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting two dat files, File1 and File2,  using

```
set1Color(n) = n==0 ? 0x008000  : n==1 ? 0xFF0000 : n==2 ? 0x000000 : 0xFF8C00
set2Color(m) = m==0 ? 0x008000  : m==1 ? 0xFF0000 : m==2 ? 0x000000 : 0x00008B

plot 'File1' u 1:2:(set1Color(column(-2))) w l  lw 1.0 lc rgb   var notitle  ,  'File2' u 1:2:(set2Color(column(-2)))  w l   lw 1.0  lc rgb var notitle
```

I want bottom three lines in File2, defined under (set2Color(colum(-2)), as dotted or dashed and one alternative dash/dot should be skipped.

Comment: what do you mean with "bottom three lines"? I understand: the last three segments of your line plot should be dotted or dashed. And what do you mean with "one alternative dash/dot should be skipped"?

Comment: plot for File2 with set2Color(m) (m=0,1,2) should be either dotted or dashed and other plot (and rest plot for File2 (0x00008B) should be  doted or dashed.  The data in File2 are very fine so plot with dot or dash may look like a solid line so I would like to skip one dot/dash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure whether I understand what you want.
My guess would be that you are looking for custom dash style?
Check `help dashtype` and the minimal example below.

**Script:** (works for gnuplot>=5.0.1, June 2015)

```
### custom dash pattern and color
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    plot for [i=1:7] '+' u 0:(i+rand(0))
unset table

myColors     = "0x008000 0xFF0000 0x000000 0xFF8C00"
myColor(col) = (n=column(col)+1, int(word(myColors, n>3 ? 4 : n)))

set dashtype 1 (5,5)
set dashtype 2 (12,12)
set key box opaque

plot $Data u 1: 2:    (myColor(-2)) w l lw 1.0 lc rgb var dt 1 title "Data1", \
        '' u 1:($2+8):(myColor(-2)) w l lw 1.0 lc rgb var dt 2 title "Data2 = shifted Data1"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. But my data are very much dense and I can not see the dot or dash. Is there any commands so that I can skip some data points?

Comment: for this check `help every`, e.g. `plot $Data u 1:2 every 10 w l` would plot every 10th datapoint.